# Array of pointers print values

Tags: c++

I have a ask question regarding this line: `cout << *ptr[i] << endl;`. 
If I change like `&ptr[i]` that and result is its addresses `0x7ffef7402a40`.

My question is: What will I have to do to get values from this `cout << &ptr[i] << endl;`, and not addresses?

```
  const int MAX = 3;

  int main () {
  int  var[MAX] = {10, 100, 500};
  int *ptr[MAX];

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  ptr[i] = &var[i]; // assign the address of integer.
  }

   for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
   cout << "Value of var[" << i << "] = ";
   cout << *ptr[i] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
  }
```

Result is:

```
  Value of var[0] = 10
  Value of var[1] = 100
  Value of var[2] = 500
```

Comment: Could you reformulate the question? I'm not sure what you're after here

Comment: If you want to print values, use `*`. If you want to print addresses, use `&`.

Comment: Since you store the **pointer** in your `int *ptr[MAX];` variable you need to **dereference** them and the `*` operator is designed for that situation

Comment: If you want to print values, use *. If you want to print addresses, use & what i will do to get values from &

Comment: @Nome See my answer.

Comment: So I have this working program: `cout << (1+2) << endl;` and it prints 3. But I want to use 1-2 instead of 1+2 but then it prints -1. What will I have to do to make it print 3 when I use 1-2?

Comment: @immibis 1-2,3 obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

> What will I have to do to get values from this cout << &ptr[i] << endl;, and not addresses?

`&` is the addressof operator. It returns the address of the object as a pointer. You could dereference that pointer to get the object at that address using the dereference operator:

```
*&ptr[i]
```

However, since the elements of your array are themselves pointers - i.e. addresses - you will still get an address with the code above. This time it is not the address where the pointer is stored, but rather the value of the pointer i.e. the address of the pointed object. To get the object that those pointers point to, you can again dereference:

```
**&ptr[i]
```

Of course, this is rather pointless since you could instead not use the addressof operator in the first place:

```
*ptr[i]
```

As you can see, dereferencing and taking the address are inverse operations and consecutive inverse operations cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is used to dereference an address (i.e. access the value stored at this address).
And `&` is used to read the address of a variable.

So

- `ptr[i]` is the address of your variables,
- `&ptr[i]` gives the address where `ptr[i]` is stored in memory
- `*ptr[i]` gives the value at address " `*ptr[i]` ", i.e. `var[i]`